# Moving map extent by x millimeters to left or right in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents, layouts, mapping

I have a layout with a map item and want to move the map itself (the extent, not the item) 5mm to the right. I am using a coverage layer with atlas. The atlas margin does not help since it's % and adds a margin to all 4 sides. 
The map has to match another map exactly when I export; moving the map item doesn't help.

I have played around with variables for the 4 extents but with no success.
Can anyone help? Any formula that would move the extent by 5 mm along the x-axis in the layout?

[image: This is what I've got]

[image: And this is what I need]

Comment: If you need this map's extents to match another one exactly, have you considered duplicating that map layout (Layout > Duplicate Layout) and then just changing the map theme/layers displayed in the new map? If your data are all in teh same project, that is...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the extents.

But the thing is you need to change both the X Min and the X Max.

Hard to say without knowing what projection system you are in, but if it is using meters you need to add 0.05 to BOTH the X Min and the X Max, do it one after the other.

It will initially look like the canvas has moved, which is has, but it will reset to the same once you add to the second X Max as well.

Comment: almost forgot: thanks for your tip. At the end, I have imported an image of the technical map as a backgound in the map composer and put a new map item exactly where it needed to be. With the right scale it kinda worked, at last. Thx anyway. Changing the extent values is tricky somehow :)